# Got stuck on a bug in posgresql using django, when i fix the bug and the re migrate nothing happens

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i did mistake which is setting a True as a default value in a

```
 ArrayField(models.CharField(...))
```

which should be in characters only (the bug isn't the import part) so anyway when i fixed it then tried to migrate it got stuck on that bug and didn't reload, i even changed it to another database and nothing happened, it happened to me the last time and i just created another project i am tired of that, is there any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you fixed it. The database caches is migrations so if you deleted the migration file, it's going to think it already migrated 001 or whichever it is. I am not sure on how to undo that, but in the past if it happened to me, I would drop all relevant tables in the database and try to migrate again

Probably should have said this first,

`python manage.py make migrations app_name && python manage.py migrate app_name` will also be needed if you are migrating an app